# Handling javascript in php

Tags: php, javascript

For example if I have this in php:

```
$test = $row['tagFormat'];
```

where $row is the query result from mysql, which is processed by mysqli_fetch_assoc, tagFormat field is stored as TEXT in database, it's value is a javascript tag, for example:

```
<script> console.log('testing');</script>
```

Now I want to do string operation on the value retrieved on variable `$test`, say replace "**testing**" with something else.
However, this won't work. Any idea why? I guess `$test` is not a string.

Comment: You have not shown what you did... I am a lil confused...

Comment: `var_dump($test);` and show us result.

Comment: PHP is executed on server. Maybe in China or somewhere else. Javascript is executed by YOUR browser.

Comment: var_dump result: string(1554) "
"

Comment: So your $test is an empty string?

Comment: I think once you get the $test string, the answer from Shredder is ok to follow. or you can use `str_replace`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value of `$test` is `"<script> console.log('testing');</script>"`

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace `testing` ..

```
$test = preg_replace('/testing/', 'hello world', $test);
```